# Is server response time considered in First Contentful Paint report via Google Lighthouse?

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, performance-testing, lighthouse

I'm trying to understand if FCP provided by Google Lighthouse contains time that server had to use to respond.

From what I can see values provided by [Browser Performance API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance_API) and Google Lighthouse are different.

For example, I've built a simple demo server that has query param to control speed of response:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');

const port = 6789;
const app = express();

app.get('/index', (req, res) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './index.html'));
  }, Number(req.query.delay || 0));
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('server started on port %s', port);
```

I make request to this server with 10s delay like `http://localhost:6789/index/?delay=10000` and after it's loaded I run the script to get value of FCP in console :

```
window.performance.getEntriesByName('first-contentful-paint')[0].startTime;
// 10113.205000001471
```

However when I run Google Lighthouse with the same 10s delay `http://localhost:6789/index/?delay=10000` I see FCP as only 0.8s seconds which less then a second, e.g.

[image]

My assumption is that Google Lighthouse doesn't include server load time, but then at what time moment it starts to measure the metric? Here's the quote from the official web doc -

> FCP measures how long it takes the browser to render the first piece of DOM content after a user navigates to your page. 
>   (source - https://web.dev/first-contentful-paint/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=devtools)

Anyone has ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bug with Lighthouse. Seen a few incidents where people have been [complaining lighthouse local result inaccuracy](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/8798075?hl=en):

Let's assume it's not a bug. Typically server response times directly affects First Contentful Paint. But nowadays (static) assets are cached by the browser or if you are using progressive web app then browser somewhat deals with slow back-ends gracefully.

Lighthouse defines FCP as:

> First Contentful Paint: first contentful paint is the first time the browser paints any content (text, image, canvas, etc) on the screen.

Lighthouse should provide screenshots / filmstrip view which should match with FCP. i.e. see if you are seeing activity on your screen short just before 1s mark even when you slow down your server response time. If so,

a) Clear Cache, reload the page and take a look at what you are seeing in the Network Panel of Google Developer Tools

b) Clear Application Data (Google Developer Tools -> Application -> Clear Storage -> clear site data. Then try run

Hope this helps.